# Is it possible to run a command that is in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that will pick a random number, and run a corresponding command to that number. I put multiple commands in a list as seen below

```
list = [cmd1(), cmd2(), cmd3(), cmd4()]
x = randint(0, len(list-1))
list[x]
```

Is there any way to run a command this way?
(I am using python 3.5)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, functions and methods are first class objects, you can assign them, pass them as arguments, etc...:

```
commands = [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4]        # omit the parenthesis (call)
current_command = random.choice(commands)
current_command()
```