# Python - Testing function without doctest

Tags: python, testing, reverse, doctest

I am currently writing two functions that reverse a string. I already have both of these functions written. Now I'm trying to write a function that has a series of test cases that can be used to test the two functions instead of calling doctest (since both functions have the same tests).

But I am unsure how to call the functions. Heres what I have.

```
def strReverseI(s):
    '''(str) -> str

    Takes a str and reverses it into a new string.

    >>> strReverseR('Hello World!')
    '!dlroW olleH'

    >>> strReverseR('CIS 210')
    '012 SIC'
    '''

    x = len(s) - 1


    new = ''
    while x >= 0:
        new = new + str(s[x]) #last char of s
        x = x - 1 #goes down back one char in s

    return new

def test_reverse(f):

    testcases = (('', ''),
                 ('a', 'a'),
                 ('xyz', 'zyx'),
                 ('testing123', '321gnitset'),
                 ('hello, world', 'dlrow ,olleh')
                )


    for i in testcases:
        if f(i) != True:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I want to pass strReverseI to test_reverse and return true if it passes all the test or false otherwise. How would I pass strReverseI to test_reverse?

I've tried "test_reverse(strReverseI) but it asks for a parameter for strReverseI. Not sure what to pass though.

Any idea?

EDIT: I realize my function test function shouldn't be testing for true or false. That was from a different set up I had for testing something else. Otherwise, I will be changing it to see if 'a' == 'a'. Regardless, the premise of the question is still the same. Still unsure on how to call the function with another function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass functions as first class objects:

```
def test_reverse(functions):
    ...
    for function in functions:
        for case in testcases:

            function(test)  #<-- call the function to test here
                            # and handle the results as needed
                            # maybe in a try/except block
```

And call the tests like this:

```
functions = [strReverseI, strReverseII]
test_reverse(functions)
```

see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868392/is-it-possible-to-run-a-command-that-is-in-a-list/36868461#36868461), for an alternate usage